# pyldap AD authentication bind_s vs simple_bind_s

Tags: python, pyldap

I am using pyldap to connect to AD server 
pyldap is providing two functions bind_s() and simple_bind_s()
can any one explain me when to use bind_s() and simple_bind_s() and which one is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**simple_bind_s()** can do simple LDAP authentication or Kerberos authentication. However, **bind_s()** can only do LDAP authentication to form connection with Active Directory server.

I mostly prefer simple_bind_s() because we need both authentication support for applications but if you're sure you will never need to implement/use kerberos authentication in your application then feel free to pick bind_s().

Following is the implementations of respective bind definitions ([Reference](https://github.com/rbarrois/python-ldap/blob/release/Lib/ldap/ldapobject.py)):

**simple_bind_s():**

```
  def simple_bind_s(self,who='',cred='',serverctrls=None,clientctrls=None):
    """
    simple_bind_s([who='' [,cred='']]) -> 4-tuple
    """
    msgid = self.simple_bind(who,cred,serverctrls,clientctrls)
    resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid, resp_ctrls = self.result3(msgid,all=1,timeout=self.timeout)
    return resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid, resp_ctrls
```

**bind_s():**

```
  def bind_s(self,who,cred,method=ldap.AUTH_SIMPLE):
    """
    bind_s(who, cred, method) -> None
    """
    msgid = self.bind(who,cred,method)
    return self.result(msgid,all=1,timeout=self.timeout)
```